# Cannot connect Raspberry Pi 3 Model B to MATLAB R2015b using MATLAB Rasp Pi support package.

Tags: pi-3, ssh, connection, putty, matlab

When I use the code:

```
 mypi = raspi('192.168.0.12','pi','raspberry')
```

It shows this error:

```
Error using raspi (line 169) Cannot establish a TCP/IP 

connection to the board with device address "192.168.0.12".

Caused by: Error using raspi (line 165) Cannot create a 

communication link with the remote server. Please check the input arguments(ADDRESS and PORT) 

and make sure the server is running. Additional Information: 

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I can ping my Pi using its ip address and connect to ssh using PuTTy but seems like MATLAB is looking for a PORT. I have no idea on what ports can be used nor how to open ports in Raspberry Pi. Help

Answer (score 0):

Please, check whether support package installation is correct version or not. If it is correct, please retry to install the support package. During the installation, you will encounter the firmware installation on the SD card of the Rasp Pi. After that, you have to confirm whether the installation is successful or not. If you didn't perform the firmware installation on the SD card, you have to try to install the firmware on the SD card, tying "targetupdater" on the matlab command line. It will do the process again.